# I need to reduce the number of arcs between nodes by choosing the closests with sort

Tags: python, numpy, gurobi

I am working on a tsp problem, as it takes a long time to execute I decided to try to reduce the number of arcs by choosing only the 5 closest places for each node. I started using `sort` to resolve my problem but I don't understand much in how to use it. my code is:

```
   import numpy as np
   import pandas as pd
   from numpy import random

   n = 21  # Houses
   N = [i for i in range(n)]
   
   arcs = [(i, j) for i in N for j in N if i != j]  

   # random coordenates 
   list_coord_x = [random.randint(100) for i in N]
   list_coord_y = [random.randint(100) for i in N]

   df = pd.DataFrame({
      "coord_x": list_coord_x,
      "coord_y": list_coord_y
    })

   # Distances for each arc
   D = {(p, j): abs(df["coord_x"][p]-df["coord_x"][j]) + abs(df["coord_y"][p]-df["coord_y"][j]) for p, j in arcs}
```

My goal is to reduce the arcs to the closest 5 so that the program runs faster. My arcs in this example are:

```
    arcs = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), (0, 10), (0, 11), (0, 12), (0, 13), (0, 14), (0, 15), (0, 16), (0, 17), (0, 18), (0, 19), (0, 20), .................................., (20, 3), (20, 4), (20, 5), (20, 6), (20, 7), (20, 8), (20, 9), (20, 10), (20, 11), (20, 12), (20, 13), (20, 14), (20, 15), (20, 16), (20, 17), (20, 18), (20, 19) ]
```

And I want for example:

```
   reduced_arcs = [(0, 1), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 10), (0, 14), (1, 3), ....., (20, 3), (20, 4), (20, 10), (20, 11), (20, 12)]
```

Because those arcs are the closest between them.

Comment: Can you please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @yannziselman thanks for the recomendation, I edit my question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can use [`scipy.spatial.distance_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html) in order to calculate the distance matrix:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix

points = [(x, y) for x,y in zip(list_coord_x, list_coord_y)]
D = distance_matrix(points, points)
```

Then, you can use the distance matrix `D` and extract the indices of the 5 lowest distance entries for each row (node):

```
x_indices, y_indices = np.where(np.argsort(D) < 5) 
reduced_arcs = [(i, j) for i, j in zip(x_indices, y_indices) if i != j]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to handle the data in either numpy or pandas as it is unnecessary difficult in a dict. As you already have pandas code in your example, you can use this code without new imports. In your example you use [Taxicab Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). If you rather want to use euclidean you have to take squares and then root or use a function like @joni suggested.

```
pd_D = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(((k[0],k[1],v) for k,v in D.items())) # so you have 
pd_D.columns = ['from','to','distance']

pd_D_reduced = pd_D.groupby('from').apply(lambda x: x.nsmallest(n=5, columns='distance'))
pd_D_reduced.droplevel(0) # to ungroup

# back to dict if you want it
D_reduced = {(row['from'],row['to']):row['distance'] for index, row in pd_D_reduced.iterrows()}
```